# Webkit document and GetElementsByTagName

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webkit, browser, webkit.net

i'm working with the webkit open source engine browser in visual basic.
I'd like to obtain the html tags conteined in the loaded web page, but when i try to use the GetElementsByTagName comand, it returns always nothing.

Do you have any ideas?

thanks in advance.
Massimo

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about VB, but I did the same thing using C# in the following way:
WebKit.DOM.Document doc1 = webKitBrowser1.Document;
WebKit.DOM.NodeList tags = doc1.getElementsByTagName("input");

Now, we can access each tag from the NodeList tags using index values, as:
WebKit.DOM.Element elm = (WebKit.DOM.Element)tags[index];

To adapt the above method in VB, you just have to change the Variable types. Concept will remain same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your capitalization is wrong? Try...

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
```

or console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")) if you are familiar with Safari/Chrome's Web Inspector.

Comment: I don't know Duopixel
when the document is complete loaded, i've defined a variable like this one:
dim x1 = webkitbrowser.document
then
i've defined another one in this mode
dim x2 = x1.getElementsByTagName("href")
and then
for each x3 in x2
----code----
next
but the loop extracts nothing, only when i insert body instead of href, it works....

thank.
Massimo.